# send newsletter with delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, delayed-job

I have and `admin_mailer`:

```
class AdminMailer < ActionMailer::Base
 def send_message_to_all_users(user, subject, body, locale)
    @user = user
    @body = body
    @locale = locale
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => subject)
  end
end
```

Inside my action on controller user:

```
def send_email_to_all_users

   users = User.all
   subject = params[:subject]
   body = params[:body]
   locale = params[:locale]
   for user in users
    User.delay(queue: "Email", priority: 20).send_message_to_all_users(user, subject, body, locale)
   end

   respond_to do |format|
    .........
   end
end
```

In my model `User`

```
class User
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created
.
.
.

#delayed jobs methods
  def self.send_message_to_all_users(user, subject, body, locale)
     AdminMailer.send_message_to_all_users(user, subject, body, locale).deliver
  end

 def deliver
  sleep 15
 end

end
```

Mailing list of `users` is very long over 20.000 emails account.

**My question is if is correct this way to send newsletter with a big mailing list, or I can do this task of better way.**

Thank you!

Comment: If you are locked into using delayed_job, take a look at this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job). The cast specifically addresses delayed mailing.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [resque_mailer](https://github.com/zapnap/resque_mailer), and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125663/how-de-we-send-out-5000-emails-per-hour-using-actionmailer-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Thank you but I am using `delayed_job` and add other background-job gem is not possible. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into the find_in_batches method here:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

In your case, you could first, find all users in batches and from there, assign each batch to your send_email_to_all_users method call (replacing the User.all with each batch.

Or, even better, you can move the entire newsletter process into its own class and encapsulate it a little (thus, still calling the method from the controller but running all of the logic in the class.)

Anyway, I think find_in_batches is what you need.