# How Can I Speed Up The Sending Of Emails Using ActionMailer from my Mac Mini Server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, postgresql-9.2, rails-postgresql

I am currently using a Mac Mini Server running OS X Server.  The server hosts several Ruby on Rails applications using Phusion Passenger where two of them uses a PostgreSQL database.  One of these applications has a mailing list database that uses ActionMailer to send emails.  As of the writing of this post the application will send 224 emails when we send a newsletter out.

We were using a GoDaddy email address in the SMTP configuration.  The emails took only five minutes to send.  However GoDaddy only allows 250 emails to be sent per day.  They also only allow you to purchase relays 50 at a time with a three month minimum.  We were not sure how well that would work for us with the growth of our mailing list.  At the rate we are growing we could add 50 people to the mailing list sooner than three months we would have already paid for.  I felt that we should visit turning on the Mail Server on our Mac Mini Server.

After getting some questions answered from Apple I was able to get the Mail Server working where I can send and receive emails.  However when I send those same emails it takes 30 minutes instead of five.  The documentation for OS X Server still has old information from Lion Server referencing Server Admin Tools which no longer apply for OS X Server.

I was hoping that the time to send emails might be the same since the database for the Rails application and the mail server were on the same machine.  However in general I understand in some cases there could be some contention with using the same resources.  Is there is any way that I can speed up the sending of the emails?  Unfortunately Server Admin Tools has not been provided for OS X Server.  The documentation for OS X Server is for the most part worthless since they reference Server Admin Tools which no longer exists.

I have posted this on Server Fault and Ask Differently.  However here I wanted to ask if there are specific things I can do in my Rails Application that may make the sending of emails using ActionMailer more efficient.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar situation where we send anywhere from 100-300 emails out to job applicants based upon interview results. Sending email through ActionMailer is slow as it usually takes several seconds per email.

That said, sending emails is one of the classic use cases for a job queue. A [similar question provided some helpful answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125663/how-de-we-send-out-5000-emails-per-hour-using-actionmailer-in-ruby-on-rails) but I can tell you that I use [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) and [ResqueMailer](https://github.com/zapnap/resque_mailer) and have been very pleased with the results. It does require standing up a [Redis](http://redis.io/) service, but it is relatively painless to do so.

Comment: I was looking at Redis to help with a localization project that I plan to start in a little while.  I believe I got the server started successfully on my development server.  I just mentioned to my husband about getting back to looking at setting up a background job for this.  I was going to try using Queue Classic which uses PostgreSQL but had a problem since my PostgreSQL server version does not match the database version.  I will definitely take a look at Reqsque and ResqueMailer.  I will post my results here.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Dan, I have another question about your solution.  What happens if the Redis server is not running for some reason?  Will it attempt to use ActionMailer to send the emails or will the application issue an error.  Note: I just set up Redis on our production server in the cloud.  I had already set it up on our development server in January.  Thanks again!

Comment: Resque/ResqueMailer will fail if Redis isn't running. To be honest I cannot recall if it raises an error or fails silently. It's best to just plan to monitor Redis to ensure it's available. We use [God](http://godrb.com/) for this.

Comment: That was my assumption.  I have a couple of other functions I plan to develop and deploy in my Rails app before I delve into setting up job queues for the first time.  Thanks so much for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I have stopped using the Mail Service on my Mac Mini Server.  I could not find a solution through Apple Technical Support.  I suffered through this until a month ago when it took almost an hour to send our emails.  I decided to look for other SMTP options.

I found out about Mandrill (created by the founders of MailChimp).  They allow you to send 12,000/month for free then a minimal amount per 1000 emails (I think).  All I had to do was to change my SMTP configuration to use Mandrill and add a couple of TXT DNS records and I was set.

Before I attempted the Mail Service I was using GoDaddy which took about eight minutes to send about 250 emails.  I used Mandrill for the first time to send emails to my entire mailing list (almost 350) and it took less than three minutes.  No ads or anything like that.  I successfully send both GoDaddy and Mandrill emails.  I have changed all my Rails applications to use the Mandrill SMTP settings.  The reports available are wonderful.

[Mandrill Web Site](https://mandrillapp.com)