# Send lots of emails as soon as possible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

Even though I use DelayedJob to send thousands of emails with a background process, it takes too many hours to complete the task. From within a library, I call "Model.deliver_..." as many times as I need. But every single call requires at least 3/4 seconds to connect with an external SMTP server.

Is there a better way to handle this?
I'm working with Rails2 and ActiveMailer.

Comment: This is all but a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517601/is-there-a-bulk-email-plugin-for-rails-apps and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125663/how-de-we-send-out-5000-emails-per-hour-using-actionmailer-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: You want a SendGrid or similar

Comment: why dont you try any threading approach

Comment: I think a threading approach would have the same issues when the number of emails arise. I'd like to execute a single transaction for all the thousands of emails I want to send. Probably an API service is the best option.